# Xamarin Facebook login after webviews deprecation

Tags: c#, xamarin, facebook-login

Facebook has deprecated login authentication on Android embedded browsers by [august](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2021/06/28/deprecating-support-fb-login-authentication-android-embedded-browsers/). Currently there is no facebook SDK 8.2+ on NUGET, is there any another way to log without using android embedded browsers?

[Facebook for developers page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/deprecating-webviews) says to ensure 8.2 SDK which is available only on javish languages

Answer (score 1):

You can try **Azure Active Directory B2C** , it  provides cloud identity management for consumer-facing web and mobile applications.  Here is a document about it [Click here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/azure-ad-b2c)